# Can I apply a condition in the where clause on a field i've selected trough an IF?

Tags: mysql

Gonna give an example since it's hard to understand what i'm talking about:

```
   SELECT a.f1, 
          b.f1, 
          IF(a.f3 <> '', a.f3, b.f3) as f3 
     FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b 
       ON b.f4 = a.f4 
    WHERE f3 = 'something'
```

Now, this won't work because i can't have an alias as a field in the where clause, so how can I apply the condition to that f3 field that's either from a or b. Preferably without putting a bunch of IFs in the where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT a.f1, b.f1,
      IF(a.f3 <> '', a.f3, b.f3) as f3
    FROM a 
    LEFT JOIN b on b.f4 = a.f4
) S
WHERE S.f3 = 'something'
```

This is actually less efficient than replacing the value with the formula itself as it will require a full scan. To improve performance (but decrease readability) you can use this query:

```
SELECT a.f1 aF1, b.f1 bF1,
  IF(a.f3 <> '', a.f3, b.f3) as f3
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b on b.f4 = a.f4
WHERE IF(a.f3 <> '', a.f3, b.f3) = 'something'
```

Comment: This query is more complex than it should be, see dweeves' post.

Comment: The example the OP provided is simplified. The question states `WHERE` clause, not `HAVING`

Comment: That's true and your solution is correct, but later the opp mentioned that the difference between where and having is not clear for him. This is why I think he didn't think about the possibility of using the having clause when he had written the question.

Comment: While I did say I'd prefer not to have IF clauses in my WHERE clause I am still gonna accept this as my answer as it's the easiest for me to implement and I find it easier to find and replace in the existing code

Answer (score 3):

WHERE won't work but HAVING will.

```
SELECT
a.f1,
b.f1,
IF(a.f3 <> '', a.f3, b.f3) as fc3
FROM 
a 
LEFT JOIN b on b.f4 = a.f4
HAVING fc3 = 'something'
```

i renamed calculcated field to avoid potential existing column name conflict

Comment: Thanks, but what's the difference between Where and Having, and can I use both in the same query?

Comment: @Bogdan, HAVING gets applied nearly last, after the results have already been gathered, so you can use aliases. Though this works, it's more efficient to eliminate records earlier, so consider the solutions where the criteria is in the WHERE or ON clause. Still +1 for academic purposes.

Comment: If I'm correct where will run after the from clause before the select clause and having will run after the select clause, however, I'm not 100% sure about this.

Answer (score 2):

Use logic.

```
 SELECT a.f1, 
          b.f1, 
          IF(a.f3 <> '', a.f3, b.f3) as f3 
     FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b 
       ON b.f4 = a.f4 
    WHERE a.f3 = 'something' OR (a.f3 == '' AND b.f3 = 'something')
```

Comment: Damn. Guess i'm not as smart as I thought I am.

Comment: Nice. This is also the type of solution that can be optimized further with a UNION and a couple of indexes.

Comment: This solution is correct, but Bogdan specified he prefers to not have further logic in the where clause.

Comment: @Bogdan: I get that every day on StackOverflow. It's a good sign: the more you know, the more you know there is you don't know. A novice will think he knows everything, a master will know there is much more to know.

Comment: @LajosArpad, OP said no IFs in the WHERE clause. :)

Comment: You are right, ignore my first comment. It seems like I worked too much today :D